# Optimal strategy in number guessing game?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Consider the following game.

1. Two players each create a passcode using the digits 0-9 four times with repetition allowed.
2. The two take turns asking a yes or no question about the opponent's passcode. Players cannot lie.
3. If one player asks "Is the password abcd?" on their turn and it is true, they win.

I am trying to find the optimal strategy. My gut feeling is that it is a binary search. Each password corresponds to an integer in the range $[0, 9999]$ so we are guaranteed to find the correct passcode in $\lceil\log_{2} 10000\rceil=14$ questions. Including the final question, the number would be $15$.

However I am unable to prove that this is the best strategy that minimizes the maximum number of questions to be asked. Is this the best strategy. If so, is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Do the players ask alternatively , no matter whether the answer was "yes" or "no" ?

Comment: The number of possible distinct answers to less than $15$ questions is $2^{13} = 8192$ which is less than the number of possible passwords.  If you can find a strategy in 14 questions, it is optimal. You may simply ask the $n$th digit of the password as written in binary, for $n$ going from $1$ to $14$.

Comment: Hmm, if it's a *competitive* game, then there might be some value to asking unbalanced questions, in the hopes of maybe getting lucky and getting an advantage over the opponent.  (Then again, depending on the calculations, it might turn out: maybe not.)  I wonder what a strategy would look like that at each point maximizes the probability of winning (vs. another player playing their respective optimal strategy).  Or maybe it might even turn out that some randomized strategy at Nash equilibrium might be needed?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think your *competitive* point is important: see my comment to Greg Martin's answer; the best strategy may vary with positions in the game.  On your *randomized strategy* point, I think all you need to do when asking a yes/no question which splits $n$ remaining numbers into $k$ and $n-k$ numbers is to choose the $k$ numbers at random.

Answer (score 1):

After $k$ questions, there are only $2^k$ possible sequences of answers. If there are more than $2^k$ possible passwords, then by the pigeonhole principle, there exist two passwords that would give the same sequence of answers, and so it's impossible to know for sure which one if the correct password.

This argument (which doesn't depend at all on the specific identities of the password, only the number $M$ possible passwords) shows that there's no strategy that works in less than $(\log M)/\log 2$ questions. Since the binary search succeeds in $\lceil (\log M)/\log 2\rceil$ questions, it's therefore optimal.

Comment: That argument may work for the first player who has the advantage of starting.  Is it obvious for the second player? For example faced with four possible numbers left when the first player has two possible numbers left, it might be better for the second player to guess a particular number rather than divide them into two pairs of two (I think that may raise the second player's conditional chance from $0.25$ to $0.375$)

Comment: As a more extreme example, if the opponent has just narrowed their choices from 2 to 1 (by guessing the wrong one out of 2), then no matter how many possibilities you have left, your only hope of winning is to guess one of them.

Comment: The OP asked (as far as I can tell) for a strategy that "minimizes the maximum number of questions to be asked", which doesn't have anything to do with the two-player structure. A strategy to optimize the chances of winning would be a different question.